# Polymer 1.0 : Bind to global element

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Sometimes you want to "share" a global element between other elements at application level. For example, a data store or other API endpoint. Is it possible and not an anti-pattern to bind a Polymer element to another Polymer element? Normally you only bind properties of elements to each other, but sometimes binding a property to another element seems useful for invoking the API of the element etc.?

For example:

```
<my-datastore id="my-ds"></my-datastore>
<my-element datastore="{{my-ds}}"></my-datastore>
```

It's possible to retrieve the datastore element by the Polymer dom API by id, but is direct binding possible? (I've seen an example of the usage of `$.my-ds` somewhere in Polymer 0.5, but this doesn't seem to work anymore in 1.0)?

Comment: You need to use mediator pattern as described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8

Comment: To bind property to native html attributes you need to use `id$={{prop name }}` But without binding I think you can't to bind id value to other component.

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-meta is such an element. You can use this element or use it as template to build a similar element yourself.